# How to prove the compound angle formula rigorously, starting only from the Taylor series definition

Tags: alternative-proof, formal-power-series

Defining $\sin{x}$ and $\cos{x}$ via their power series, over the real numbers.
With no allusion to complex numbers, or geometrical diagrams, how can one prove
$$\forall x,y\in\mathbf{R},\\\sin{(x+y)} = \sin{x}\cos{y}+\cos{x}\sin{y} $$
starting from the barest bone theorems of power series and differentiable functions?

I have attempted to expand both sides via their power series representation and can see that the terms do look like they're matching, but a rigorous arguement feels out of reach. All I know is that the re-arrangement of terms on either side is valid since the series are absolutely convergent, but still, how to prove that the terms on both sides match for all higher order terms? (I've only checked the first and third order).

Apart from this method, is there a simpler way to prove it (once again, without complex numbers and starting only from the taylor series definitions). Similar to how one is able to prove $\sin^{2}{x}+\cos^{2}{x}=1$ via differentiating and then plugging in $x=0$. Is there a proof of the compound angle formula that is similar in spirit to the above?

Comment: You can also do it without alluding to differentiation at all, by using Cauchy Product. This is the method generally used to prove exp(x+y)=exp(x)exp(y) starting with the power series definition

Answer (score 2):

You asked

> Similar to how one is able to prove $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ via differentiating and then plugging in $x=0$. Is there a proof of the compound angle formula that is similar in spirit to the above?

Assume that the functions $\,s(x)\,$ and $\,c(x)\,$ satisfy

$$ s'(x)=c(x),\;\; s(0)=0,\;\; c'(x)=-s(x),\;\; c(0)=1. \tag1$$

Assume that $\,y\,$ is arbitrary but fixed. Define the functions

$$ f(x) := s(x)c(y) + c(x)s(y),\quad  g(x) := s(x+y).\tag2 $$

The second derivative of $\,f(x)\,$ w.r.t. $x$ using
equation $(1)$ is

$$ f''(x) = -s(x)c(y) - c(x)s(y) = -f(x). \tag3 $$

Note that $\, f(0) = g(0) = s(y)\,$ using equation $(1).\,$
Similarly, $\, f'(0) = g'(0) = c(y).\,$

Note that

$$ s'(x+y) = c(x+y),\quad c'(x+y) = -s(x+y).\tag4 $$
Thus,

$$ g''(x) = (s'(x+y))' = -s(x+y) = -g(x). \tag5 $$

Let $\,h(x) := f(x)-g(x).\,$ Now we already know after
equation $(3)$ that $\,h(0) = h'(0) = 0.\,$
But now we have $\,h''(x) = -h(x)\,$ which implies that
$\,h''(0) = 0\,$ and hence all derivatives of $\,h(x)\,$
are equal to $0$. The power series expansion of $\,h(x)\,$
has all coefficients $0$ and therefore $\,h(x)\equiv 0.\,$
This implies that $\,f(x)\equiv g(x).\,$ Equation $(2)$ implies
$$ s(x+y) = s(x)c(y) + c(x)s(y). \tag 6 $$

Comment: ...and this is true no matter what $y$ (which $f$ and $g$ depend on as a parameter) is. +1.

Comment: Is there an elementary proof of that statement? Or at least for this specific case?

Comment: @AnshumanAgrawal What specific case of what statement and what do you consider not elementary?

Comment: Unique solution to ode

Comment: @AnshumanAgrawal Good question! I will have to add more reasoning.